# Matching strings in VBS

Tags: vbscript, string-comparison

Were currently working on a script that reads the current users information from out ActiveDirectory server nad checks the Groups to see what printers they require.

We have come across an issue that were struggling to get around, Using the built in function `InStr` where trying to match the group name in a string like so:

```
cn=GG_RoomA1,dc=Security Group cn=GG_RoomA2,dc=Security Group ...
```

This string goes up to `GG_Room13`

```
'EDC Room A1
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA1)) Then
    objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA1_P002765"
    objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA1_P002765" 
End if
```

The variables are as follows:

- `strGroup` | is the large string of groups
- `GG_RoomA1` is a constant set and has the value of `cn=cn=GG_RoomA1`

The issue where having is that if your a member of the group `GG_RoomA10` you will also get `GG_RoomA1`.

Is there a way we can specifically match only one group with the following factors,

The whole code is here.

```
Option Explicit
'On error resume next
'Declare Variables
Dim objNetwork, objUser, CurrentUser, strGroup, objFSO, Printers, i

'Declare Constant Groups for Printer Locations
Const GG_RoomA1 = "cn=GG_RoomA1"
Const GG_RoomA2 = "cn=GG_RoomA2"
Const GG_RoomA4 = "cn=GG_RoomA4"
Const GG_RoomA6 = "cn=GG_RoomA6"
Const GG_RoomA7 = "cn=GG_RoomA7"
Const GG_RoomA8 = "cn=GG_RoomA8"
Const GG_Room_CopiersA6_A8 = "cn=GG_Room_CopiersA6-A8"
Const GG_RoomA9 = "cn=GG_RoomA9"
Const GG_RoomA10 = "cn=GG_RoomA10"
Const GG_RoomL1 = "cn=GG_RoomL1"
Const GG_RoomL7 = "cn=GG_RoomL7"
Const GG_RoomL9 = "cn=GG_RoomL9"
Const GG_RoomC1 = "cn=GG_RoomC1"
Const GG_RoomC3 = "cn=GG_RoomC3"
Const GG_Room2 = "cn=GG_Room2"
Const GG_Room3 = "cn=GG_Room3"
Const GG_Room4_5 = "cn=GG_Room4&5"
Const GG_Room6 = "cn=GG_Room6"
Const GG_Room8_9 = "cn=GG_Room8&9"
Const GG_Room10L = "cn=GG_Room10L"
Const GG_Room10R = "cn=GG_Room10R"
Const GG_Room11 = "cn=GG_Room11"
Const GG_Room12 = "cn=GG_Room12"
Const GG_Room12A = "cn=GG_Room12A"
Const GG_Room12B = "cn=GG_Room12B"
Const GG_Room13 = "cn=GG_Room13"
Const GG_Room14_15 = "cn=GG_Room14&15"
Const GG_Room16 = "cn=GG_Room16"
Const GG_Room17 = "cn=GG_Room17"
Const GG_Room_FRAnnexeA = "GG_Room_FRAnnexeA"
Const GG_Room_FRAnnexeB = "GG_Room_FRAnnexeB"
Const GG_Room_FRAnnexeC = "GG_Room_FRAnnexeC"
Const GG_Room_FR02 = "GG_Room_FR02"
Const GG_Room_FR05 = "GG_Room_FR05"
Const GG_Room_FR10 = "GG_Room_FR10"
Const GG_Room_FR11 = "GG_Room_FR11"
Const GG_Room_FR13 = "GG_Room_FR13"
Const GG_Room_FR14 = "GG_Room_FR14"
Const GG_Room_FR16 = "GG_Room_FR16"
Const GG_Room_Ruiz = "GG_Room_Ruiz"
Const GG_Room_NLAdmin = "GG_Room_NLAdmin"
Const GG_Room_NLManagers = "GG_Room_NLManagers"
Const GG_Room_NLShared = "GG_Room_NLShared"
Const GG_Room_NLSupport = "GG_Room_NLSupport"
Const GG_Room_Shepwell = "GG_Room_Shepwell"

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objUser = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set CurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objUser.UserName)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strGroup = LCase(Join(CurrentUser.MemberOf))

'Remove all Network printers but not local printers

Set Printers = objNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections

For i = 0 to Printers.Count - 1 Step 2

    If Left(ucase(Printers.Item(i+1)),2) = "\\" Then
        'WScript.Echo Printers.Item(i+1)
        objNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection Printers.Item(i+1)
    End If
Next

'EDC Room A1
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA1)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA1_P002765"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA1_P002765" 
End if

'EDC Room A2
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA2)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA2_P002280"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA2_ARM207"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA2_P002280" 
End if

'EDC Room A4
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA4)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA4_P002012"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA4_P002175"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA4_P000169"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA4_P002874"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA4_P002012"
End if

'EDC Room A5 and A6
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA6)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA5_P001710"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA5_P000640"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA6_P002821"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA6_MX3100N"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA6_P002821"
End if

'EDC Room A7
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA7)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA7_P000804"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA7_P002241"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA7_ARM350"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA7_P002241"
End if

'EDC Room A8
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA8)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA8_P001720"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA8_P002820"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA8_P002861"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA8_MX550U"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA8_P002820"
End if

'EDC Room A6-A8 Copiers
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_CopiersA6_A8)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA6_MX3100N"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA8_MX550U"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA7_ARM350"
End if

'EDC Room A9
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA9)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA9_P002011"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA9_P002819"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA9_P002819"
End if

'EDC Room A10
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA10)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA10_P002827"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA6_MX3100N"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA10_P002827"
End if

'EDC Room L1
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomL1)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL1_IRC2880"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL1_P000474"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL1_P002420"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL1_P002420"
End if

'EDC Room L7
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomL7)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL7_P002603"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL7_P002260"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL7_MX363N"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL7_P002603"
End if

'EDC Room L9
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomL9)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL9_P000930"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmL9_P000930"
End if

'EDC Room C1
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomC1)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmC1_P000476"
'objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\???"
'objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\???"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmC1_P000476"
End if

'EDC Room C3
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomC3)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmC3_P002828"
'objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\???"
'objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\???"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmC3_P002828"
End if

'EDC Room 2
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room2)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm2_P000229"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRM2_P000442"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm2_P000229"
End if

'EDC Room 3
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room3)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm3_P001736"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm3_P001736"
End if  

'EDC Room 4 & 5
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room4_5)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm4&5_P000751"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRM4&5_P001904"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm4&5_P000751"
End if

'EDC Room 6
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room6)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm6_P002806"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRM6_P002562"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm6_P002806"
End if

'EDC Room 8 & 9
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room8_9)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm8&9_P001775"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm8&9_P001775"
End if 

'EDC Room 10L
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room10L)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm10_P002379"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm10_P002380"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm10_P002764"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm10_P002380"
End if

'EDC Room 10R
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room10R)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm10_P002379"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm10_P002380"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm10_P002764"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm10_P002379"
End if  

'EDC Resource Room (Room 11)
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room11)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm11_MX4501N"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm11_MX700U"
End if

'EDC Room 12
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room12)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm12_P002224"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm12_P002224"
End if  


'EDC Room 12A
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room12A)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm12A_P000786"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm12A_P000792"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm12A_P000786"
End if  

'EDC Room 12B
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room12B)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm12B_P002781"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm12B_P002781"
End if  

'EDC Room 13
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room13)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm13_P001784"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm13_P002818"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm13_P002818"
End if

'EDC Room 14 & 15
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room14_15)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRM14&15_P002782"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm14&15_P002782"
End if  

'EDC Room 16
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room16)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm16_P001360"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm16_P001512"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm16_P001512"
End if

'EDC Room 17
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room17)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm17_P001045"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm17_P001936"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm16_P001512"
End if


'Field Road Admin
'IS THIS NEEDED - IS FR16 the same thing
'If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room???)) Then
'objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAdmin_P000230"
'objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAdmin_P000525"
'objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRm16_P001512"
'End if

'Field Road AnnexeA SEN
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FRAnnexeA)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexe_P002809"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexe_P002805"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexeSEN_ARM256"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexe_P002805"
End if

'Field Road AnnexeB DISABILITY
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FRAnnexeB)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexe_P002312"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexeDIS_ARM256"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexe_P002312"
End if

'Field Road AnnexeC LAC
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FRAnnexeC)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexeLAC_P000991"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexeLAC_P001050"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRAnnexeLAC_P001050"
End if

'Field Road FR02
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FR02)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRMain_MX3100N"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRMain_MX363N"
End if


'Field Road FR05
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FR05)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRMain_P002436"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRMain_P002436"
End if  

'Field Road FR10
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FR10)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRRm10_P000438"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRRm10_P000438"
End if  


'Field Road FR11
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FR11)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRRm11_P002013"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRRm11_P002013"
End if  


'Field Road FR13
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FR13)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRRm13_P001049"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRRm13_P001049"
End if  


'Field Road FR14
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FR14)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRRm14_P001041"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRRm14_P001041"
End if  


'Field Road FR16
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_FR16)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAdmin_P000230"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRAdmin_P000525"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRAdmin_P000230"
End if

'Field Road RUIZ
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_Ruiz)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRRuiz_P001072"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRRuiz_P001867"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\FRRuiz_MX283N"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\FRRuiz_P001867"
End if  

'New Leaf Admin
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_NLAdmin)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCNL_IRC3580"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCNL_P002871"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCNL_P002871"
End if  

'New Leaf Managers
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_NLManagers)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCNL_P002306"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCNL_P002206"
End if  

'New Leaf Shared
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_NLShared)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCNL_IRC3580"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCNL_IRC3580"
End if  

'New Leaf Support
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_NLSupport)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCNL_P002016"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCNL_P002016"
End if  

'Shepwell
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_Room_Shepwell)) Then
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\SHEP_P000436"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\SHEP_P002017"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\SHEP_P002017"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\SHEP_P000436"
End if  


Dim answer
answer=MsgBox("Printer Script is Complete!",0,"Confirmation")


'End Printer Script
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the group string it looks like all the rooms have a comma behind it so you could change your `If` to:

```
If InStr(LCase(strGroup), LCase(GG_RoomA1 & ",")) Then
```

So that it will only match if there's a comma right behind the room string, or if the last room won't have a comma behind it you could do the following combination:

```
If InStr(LCase(strGroup), LCase(GG_RoomA1 & ",")) Or LCase(Right(strGroup, Len(GG_RoomA1))) = LCase(GG_RoomA1) Then
```

Comment: Probably a better solution than mine, I oversimplified the problem!

Comment: @Tom: Possibly, I'm still slightly confused though so I think we'll have to wait and see what Robert's colleague says about our answers.

Comment: yea i have no clue about VB, bt from what i head it has dictionaries and pretty decent string comparison functions, He currently on lunch and will be back so ill let you guys know, I need to double check the string to make sure that group name is always proceeded by a `,`. Good Solution as well +1

Comment: This is what seemed to have worked, the last `,` was still there as the string is like `dc=GG_GroupName, dc=Location, dc=internal`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this right, you have a string which could be:

```
GG_RoomA10
```

or

```
GG_RoomA1
```

And you wish to match only one, but not match RoomA1 if it is RoomA10.

You could try:

```
'Matches A1 but not A10
If InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA1)) AND NOT InStr(strGroup, lcase(GG_RoomA10))
```

This would return the following results:

```
"GG_RoomA1" = true
"GG_RoomA10" = false
"GG_RoomA1/GG_RoomA10" = false
```

So if they are independent of each other, IE, will never appear in the same string you are good to go.  If they could appear in the same string, it get's a little more complicated.

Just a suggestion, your design of your code is a little repetative which is usually indicative of a bad design, you might want to go back to the drawing board with this one (IE, do you have DB connectivity?).  A whole load of if's and not's are going to be hard to maintain.

Comment: The code was made by another college in which he turned to me for help, i have no clue about VBScript and it was a long process for me to explain ideas such as Dictionaries and Loops etc, but he said this is the only problem he has and if he can get past it he would be happy, When he is available to check see if your answer is working ill accept.

Comment: The question says that it goes up to room 13 though, so you'd have to change that it's not 11, 12 or 13 as well.

Comment: And one of us misunderstood the question, because I thought `"GG_RoomA1/GG_RoomA10"` should return `true`. But now I'm not sure...

Comment: Yea, He would find that out but he dont mind applying the solution several times.

Comment: @ho1 yes I think it should return true as well but wasn't sure if they would ever be found in the same string, which upon re-reading, it appears they can.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to use `For Each` to process the groups one at a time rather than relying on substring methods.

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objUser = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set CurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objUser.UserName)

For Each strGroup in CurrentUser.MemberOf
    strGroupPath = "LDAP://" & strGroup
    Set objGroup = GetObject(strGroupPath)
    strGroupName = objGroup.CN

    ' Set up printers based on group
    If strGroupName = "GG_RoomA1" Then
        objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA1_P002765"
        objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA1_P002765"
    End If

    If strGroupName = "GG_RoomA2" Then
        objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA2_P002280"
        objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA2_ARM207"
        objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\edw-sr-img\EDCRmA2_P002280"
    End If

    'TODO: Handle other groups
Next
```